# How to have a timestamp that adjusts to the current day automatically

Tags: timestamp, pine-script-v5, indicator

I would need this below timestamp to be dynamic and adjust to the current day all the time, but I want the hours to stay 9:30 all the time.  Just the date needs to follow the day all the time.  Is that possible?

timestamp(2022,06,27,9,30,0)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but try the approach below.
timestamp(year,month,dayofmonth,9,30,0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  In my working code I have myVar = timestamp(2022,07,15,9,30,0) and when I change it to myVar = timestamp(year,month,dayofmonth,9,30,0) it doesn't work anymore.